# Unable to get text using selenium web driver while iterating over multiple links stored in an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is a continuation of my previous question "[Web scraping using selenium and beautifulsoup.. trouble in parsing and selecting button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752309/web-scraping-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-trouble-in-parsing-and-selectin)". I could solve the previous problem, but I am now stuck on the below.

I got the links from previously stored in an array.

Then, I am trying to visit all the links stored in a list named `StartupLink`.
The information I need to scrape and store in an array is in `div` `class=content` tag. For some link, the above `div` tag contains `div` `hidden_more` with javascript enabled click events. So I am handling the exception. However, the loop runs fine and visits links but after first two links it gives NA output even though there is the presence of `div content` tag, it also shows no error (that's unacceptable).

The array contains 400 links to visit with similar div `content` element.
Where am I going wrong here?

```
Description=[]
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for link in StartupLink:

    try:
        driver.get(link)
        sleep(5)
        more = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="hidden_more"]')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of(more))
        sleep(5)
        element.click()
        sleep(5)
        page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]').text
        sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:# NoSuchElementException:
        driver.start_session()
        sleep(5)
        page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]').text
        sleep(5)
        print(str(e))
    if page == '':
        page = "NA"
        Description.append(page)
    else:
        Description.append(page)
    print(page)
```

Comment: You say the div content tag is present, is there actually data in there?

Comment: Yes data is there but it's not printing which I have tried printing while debuging,except the first two link it visits, for rest all links there are data, for some yes it isn't there. But, for the tag which contains data also it's not printing.